# How do I iterate through all records and pass database value to a variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, nokogiri

I have two tables, "Que" and "Opts".

I want to iterate through all the records in Que and add them to the variables `rikt_nr`, `start_nr` and `end_nr`, because they will go on the end of a URL, which will look like:

```
api.url.number=8-00001
```

How do I make it iterate through Que and pass `rikt_nr`, `start_nr` and `end_nr` to the rest of the code?

The Que table has these fields:

```
create_table "ques", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "rikt_nr"
  t.integer  "start_nr"
  t.integer  "end_nr"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

and Opts has these fields:

```
create_table "opts", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "numbers"
  t.string   "operator"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

This is the code:

```
Que.all.each do | que |

  url = "http://api.url.number=" 

  que.rikt_nr = rikt_nr 
  que.start_nr = start_nr  
  que.end_nr = end_nr  
  st_en = start_nr..end_nr 

  st_en.each do |nr| 
    full_url = "#{url}" + rikt_nr.to_s + "-"+ nr.to_s

    doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(full_url)) 

    number = doc.at('Number').text  
    operator = doc.at('Name').text 

    number_operator = "#{number}" + ";" + " #{operator}"

    number_operator 

    save = @opts.create(:numbers => number, :operator => operator) 
  end
end
```

Comment: Please format your code so it's more readable. That helps everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out this.

The problem was here:

```
que.rikt_nr = rikt_nr 
que.start_nr = start_nr  
que.end_nr = end_nr  
st_en = start_nr..end_nr
```

so I changed it to:

```
Que.all.each do | que |

  url = "http://api.url.number=" 

  st_en = que.start_nr..que.end_nr 

  st_en.each do |nr| 
    full_url = "#{url}" + que.rikt_nr.to_s + "-"+ nr.to_s

    doc = Nokogiri::XML(open(full_url)) 

    number = doc.at('Number').text  
    operator = doc.at('Name').text 

    number_operator = "#{number}" + ";" + " #{operator}"

    number_operator 

    save = @opts.create(:numbers => number, :operator => operator) 

  end
end
```

and it now works.

Comment: Don't inject variables into a URL, use the URI class to modify the URL and add any parameters to it. Interpolating variables can result in unencoded values which will make the URL invalid. URI will follow the spec and encode them correctly for you. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390602/open-uri-invalid-uri-error-encoding-escaping-not-affecting/26393929#26393929.