# ruby on rails import csv from upload file to Active Records using Smarter csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, import, rails-activerecord, smartercsv

I hit a roadblock here and need help. I want to be able to import csv file to my Active Record. Either with SmarterCSV or some other way

Here is my database

```
create_table "ques", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "rikt_nr"
    t.integer  "start_nr"
    t.integer  "end_nr"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

here is my view

```
<h2>Import Ques</h2>  

<%= form_tag import_ques_path, multipart: true do %>  
   <%= file_field_tag :file %>  
   <%= submit_tag "Import" %>  
<% end %>
```

here is my route

```
resources :ques do  
  collection { post :import }  
end  
  root to: 'ques#index'
```

and my controller

```
def import  
  Que.import(params[:file])  
   redirect_to root_url, notice: "Ques imported."  
end
```

and the model

```
def self.import(file)  
  CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|  
   Que.create! row.to_hash  
  end  
end
```

and the csv file is looking like this

```
Id;Rikt nr;Start nr;End nr;Created at;Updated at
1;8;4486550;4486650;October 28, 2014 08:42;October 28, 2014 08:42
2;8;4486700;4486755;October 28, 2014 08:42;October 28, 2014 08:42
```

I have looked at all sort of guides, but I just cant get it to work.

Comment: Where are you indicating that you're separator is a semicolon instead of a comma?

Comment: Dosent smartercsv fix that ?

Comment: Sorry, I copies too much of your code. Just skip the `.to_hash`. I updated my answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For anybody else that is having a problem with this. This is how I solved it. First off change the csv file to have "," as the delimiters

Then use the code I have, but change the  controller to this

```
def import
      csv_file = params[:file].read
      CSV.parse(csv_file) do |row|
      ques = Que.create(rikt_nr: row[0], start_nr: row[1], end_nr: row[2])
      ques.save
    end
 redirect_to ques_path, notice: "Que added"

end
```

and it works

Answer (score 3):

First: you don't use `smarter_csv` in your example, but standard Ruby CSV.
Second: `smarter_csv` gives you options to specify the delimiting character but doesn't `auto detect` it.

in conclusion, you `import` should look like

```
def self.import(file)  
  SmarterCSV.process(file.path, col_sep: ';') do |row|  
   Que.create! row 
  end  
end
```

Comment: wheh I did add your code it just says "undefined method `to_hash'"

Comment: Sorry, I copied too much of your code. Just skip the `.to_hash`. I updated my answer.

Comment: thx Martin, I have been working just wiht csv files now and I understand in now. thx for your help!!